# Import binary file in my library through a name

Tags: python, import

I want to import a binary file within a module through a name.

For example:

```
mylibrary
|
+---test (name of submodule)
    |
    +---TestData (name representing the binary file)
    |
    +---testdata.bin (the actual binary file)
```

I want:

```
import numpy as np
import mylibrary.test.TestData as TestData
with open(TestData, 'rb') as f:
    np_array = np.load(f)
```

Is that a good idea? How to make this work?

Comment: Why would you do this? You don't need to "import" a file to read it.

Comment: for unit testing. I want to put unit tests into a sub module, just like what numpy/scipy did. The unit tests need test data. If I don't put the test data into the test submodule, the unit tests can't find it. I could find the root path of the installed library and then find the path to the TestData, but it is tedious for writing the tests.

Comment: You can put it in the submodule, but you don't have to "import" it. `open` will open it as long as the path is right.

Comment: never mind, I figured this out. Just put TestData as a global string for path that points to testdata.bin within a sub-module

Comment: Okay, you can either answer your own question or delete it. :)

Comment: Why delete it? :D Someone else can use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it like that, Python will not recognize non Python files when importing. But you can add `__init__.py` file to the `test` folder and place in it:

```
import os
TestData = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "testdata.bin")
```

Then you can easily load it in your other projects as:

```
import numpy as np
from mylibrary.test import TestData
with open(TestData, 'rb') as f:
    np_array = np.load(f)
```